# How can I load parquet files in BigQuery forcing string type?

Tags: string, google-bigquery, parquet

I would like to load data from a parquet file into BigQuery using only the STRING type for all my attributes. I would like to force all data to stay in STRING type to avoid any future loading failure due to type incompatibility with other files.

I have parquet files with different types : `STRING, FLOAT...`

And I have created a bigquery table with STRING types only.

I run this command to load the data from my parquet file into BigQuery :

```
bq load --source_format=PARQUET --noreplace --noautodetect --parquet_enum_as_string=true --decimal_target_types=STRING [project]:[dataset].[tables] gs://[bucket]/[file].parquet
```

I get this error:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job '[project]:[job]': Provided Schema does not match Table [project]:[dataset].[table]. Field [attribut] has
changed type from STRING to FLOAT
```

I tried to import the parquet data with the same command into a non-existing table, it worked with the `FLOAT` attributes.

As you can see, I tried adding the parameters

`--noautodetect`

`--parquet_enum_as_string=true`

`--decimal_target_types=STRING`

to force the conversion to string and stop auto-detection but this does not solve my needs.

Do you know how can I force `STRING` type, please?

Comment: Parquet files have schema info within. Read this link https://hackolade.com/help/Parquetschema.html. Schema should match b/w table and file

Comment: Can't we force STRING casting while loading to big query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change how to parse data[1] type when loading data with a parquet file. There are some parquet data types that can be converted into multiple BigQuery data types[2].
What you have to do is to go to the Parquet schema and add the data type that you want to parse to BigQuery.

It should look like this:

```
optional float my_col (STRING);
```

And another good practice is to add the schema to the `bq load command` like:

```
bq load --source_format=PARQUET --noreplace --noautodetect --parquet_enum_as_string=true --decimal_target_types=STRING [project]:[dataset].[tables] gs://[bucket]/[file].parquet timestamp_col:TIMESTAMP,integer_col:INTEGER,string_col:STRING,my_col:STRING
```

[1]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#parquet_conversions
[2]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#type_conversions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check your first option. For the second option: when a table already exists, adding a schema creates an error because it conflicts with the table schema + I have too many tables and too many attributes. I can't explore this option.

Comment: @Ailyc let me know if that helped you.